# Retrieve rows with similarities

Tags: sql

I have a database which contains user submitted URL's.
I want to retrieve every link which contains similarities.
For example:

http://google.com

[http://google.nl](http://google.com/something)

http://google.com/something

So far my self-join queries failed. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The main problem is how to detect similarities.

Comment: `So far my self-join queries failed.` can you put that query here and your table schema

Comment: you may try with the LIKE construct

Comment: I found out that which i was doing was to count every row for the duplicate rows. Duplicate rows is not what i need. I need rows which share similarities.

Comment: Describe that similarity. `www.some.com/something` and `www.other.com/something` are similar or not?   `www.some.some2.some3.com` and `www.other.some.some3.com` are similar or not? Give us algorith described in words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data is always url's I would find some way to normalize the data, so do things like:

- remove http:// and http://
- remove top level domains, .co.uk, .nl, .com (you can get a list from wikipedia or somewhere)
- remove every querystring so if you have a ?, delete that and everything after it, so your normalized string becomes:

Source:

`http://www.google.com
https://news.google.com
http://google.com
https://google.com/hello?wht=sessiojjkahfjkafhadjkfhajk
https://google.com/hello?qekqrjeqkej`

Ends up as:

`google.com
news.google.com
google.com
google.com/hello
google.com/hello`

If you wanted to remove things like change news.google.com to google.com you could also get rid of any prefixes pretty easily and the same is for the /hello in google.com/hello

It really depends on what data is useful for you but get it in a state where matching is easy, rather than trying to find a way to generate matches.

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE MY_FIELD LIKE 'http://google.%'
```

Where % is called 'wildcard' and means 'any number of any kind of character'.

Comment: I'm aware of the wildcard, but the use of the link "www.google.com" was just an example. The link could be anything. The problem is to detect the similarities.